# how refresh widget with flutter ? (using setState ?)

Tags: flutter

I have a button on my app page and when i click on it, it contacts my php/MySQL api and do the work. After it displays an alert dialog for say me if all is correct or not and when i click on OK i would like it refresh the datas displayed on screen. The datas are loaded with futurebuilder and goes from my api. When i click on the button it deletes the datas selected so when i click OK on alert dialog i would like datas disappears and so it needs to be refreshed. Using setstate is perhaps the solution but when i have tried set setstate it doesn't work. DO you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setState` inside `onPressed`:

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

For Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> listOfStr = ["loin", "dog", "cat"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: listOfStr.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    listOfStr.removeAt(index);
                  });
                },
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                title: Text(listOfStr[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works well. I need put setstate and in it i have called the function which display datas so it refresh :) I accept your answer thanks a lot my friend